# How to check if element (checkbox) is on stage?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attr, prop

I was originally targeting a checkbox like this:

```
$("#" + tempid_array[0] + " #" + tempid_array[1]).click();
```

which also executed any bound event/actions it had tied to it... and this -does- work.

I however wanted to check if the target checkbox was on the stage before executing this. (otherwise the bound events would not be executed and I would need to execute the same actions manually.)

my question is 2 part:

1.) why is this -not- finding the target checkbox on the stage (when it 100% is)

I use the same selector/syntax for executing the click() event??

```
//check if checkbox is on stage
if($("#" + tempid_array[0] + " #" + tempid_array[1]).lenth > 0){
    //checkbox found, un-checking   
    console.log("checkbox is on stage");    
    //let bound checkbox event do everything    
    $("#" + tempid_array[0] + " #" + tempid_array[1]).click();
    //$("#" + tempid_array[0] + "#"+tempid_array[1]).prop("checked", false);
    //$("#" + tempid_array[0] + "#"+tempid_array[1]).attr("checked", false);
}else{
    //checkbox not found
    console.log("checkbox -not- on stage"); 
    //do everything ourselves
    //etc...etc...
}
```

the above always returns false, checkbox not found on stage?

2.) while the click() event on the checkbox is triggered (when used standalone and not in the if() statement...  I can NOT get the prop or attr variants to work?  the checkbox still has the checkbox displayed (as if it was selected still)

What am I doing wrong?  Syntax?  wrong approach completely?

My main question is how can I detect is the checkbox is on the stage anywhere?
The second question was more curiosity, as the click() event fires no problem..but the prop/attr does nothing?

Comment: instead of triggering a click why not create a function. That way you can reuse the code

Comment: The real question is why do you have to target an element with two ID's, ID's are unique, and there should only be one single element with any given ID.

Comment: @ miro-

1.) I would still need a working way to uncheck the target checkbox on stage..  (which wasnt working)

@ adeneo   These are dynamically created, so there is 1 unique parent ID..  and then the checkbox ID..

I understand the ID should be unique to the page, (and it usually is, however in a rare circumstance there could be a different, unique parent ID with the same checkbox ID's

Thanks being said, neither of these comments stayed on point of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.lenth > 0
```

should be

```
.length > 0
```

and you're missing a space in the `.prop` - should be `" #"`, i.e.

```
$("#" + tempid_array[0] + " #"+tempid_array[1]).prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: OMG!..haha  thanks for that.  I guess when you make the typo yourself you just dont see it!

Answer accepted and thanks for the second pair of eyes! 

Also thanks for the tip about the missing space for the prop/attr attempt!